Why can’t CMake find curl when cross compiling?
I’m trying to add curl to my project. I made some tests on native build, and it works fine like this:
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CURL_LIBRARIES})

However, I also need to cross-compile my code. Since I am targeting an old Debian stretch system, I compiled the correct version of GCC and glibc, and it works fine for other local libraries. I also made a copy of the target sysroot with this script:
rsync -au --progress \
      --include=/lib/*** \
      --include=/opt/*** \
      --include=/usr \
      --include=/usr/include/*** \
      --include=/usr/lib/*** \
      --include=/usr/local \
      --include=/usr/local/lib/*** \
      --include=/usr/local/include/*** \
      --include=/usr/share \
      --include=/usr/share/cmake-3.7/*** \
      --exclude='*' \
      <target_system>:/ \
      /opt/<local-sysroot>

However, when cross compiling, now configuration fails:
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR) (found version
  "7.81.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindCURL.cmake:181 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:162 (find_package)

notice that 7.81.0 is the version on my host system, while the one present on the target (7.52.1) doesn’t get found. However, my toolchain file contains:
set(root_fs_dir /opt/<local-sysroot>)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${root_fs_dir})
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${root_fs_dir})
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH ${root_fs_dir})

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# search headers and libraries in the target environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)

so it should search only the sysroot packages, and find them, since I am pointing it to the right directory (at least this is what seems to be happening with other libraries, not used with find_package but directly with target_link_libraries). thinking it could be due to the different version path of CMake module search, I created the symlink
ln -s /opt/box-root-fs/usr/share/cmake-3.7/ /opt/box-root-fs/usr/share/cmake-3.22

but the error is still present
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR) (found version
  "7.81.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindCURL.cmake:181 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:162 (find_package)

so, why can’t CMake find the libraries, if the module file is present? Thank you!

EDIT:
the resulting sysroot contains these files:
$ find /opt/box-root-fs/ -iname *curl*
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/curl
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/curl/curlver.h
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/curl/curlrules.h
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/curl/curl.h
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/curl/curlbuild.h
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/curl
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pycurl-7.43.0.egg-info
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pycurl.cpython-35m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/lib/python3.5/__pycache__/macurl2path.cpython-35.pyc
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/lib/python3.5/macurl2path.py
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcurl.a
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcurl-gnutls.so.4
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcurl.so.3
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.4.0
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcurl.so
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcurl.la
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig/libcurl.pc
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcurl.so.4.4.0
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcurl.so.4
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcurl-gnutls.so.3
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/lib/python2.7/macurl2path.py
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/lib/python2.7/macurl2path.pyc
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindCURL.cmake
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/share/cmake-3.7/Help/variable/CTEST_CURL_OPTIONS.rst
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/share/cmake-3.7/Help/module/FindCURL.rst


EDIT 2
as per comment request, I'm posting here the output of
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../TC-arm-linux-gnueabihf.cmake --debug-find ..

since it's too long, I put it in a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/eLR8h1bn

Are you sure curl is installed in /opt/<local-sysroot>?  The libraries and headers?

@StephenNewell i think yes, as i used rsync. i added the file list in the question

Run cmake with additional option --debug-find. That way CMake will print which exact directories are searched during "find" commands like find_library, find_path.

Copying modules shipped with CMake is at least pointless. These modules are part of CMake installation, not a part of cross-compiling environment. If you want to use specific CMake for configure your project, then just run appropriate cmake executable.

@Tsyvarev thank you, but I'm sorry I can't understand what do you mean. Aren't .cmake files installed by packages/libraries, and shipped independently from CMake? And what do you mean with "run appropriate cmake executable"? I can't use the target version of CMake, as it is an arm machine

Files under /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules are part of CMake itself and installed with CMake. Most of those files are named as Find<..>.cmake and describe the way how CMake searches packages. Some packages are shipped with .cmake files, but those files are named as <...>Config.cmake or config-<...>.cmake. "I can't use the target version of CMake, as it is an arm machine" - So you shouldn't feed modules, written for that CMake, to CMake on your host machine.

@Tsyvarev thanks, that means I have to change my question. If you want you can turn this comment into an answer, or I can do that if you prefer. Thank you!

"that means I have to change my question." - No, I don't ask you to change a question. I just told you that one of your approaches, which you have listed in the question post, is not good. But for debug your problem you need to provide more details. E.g. relevant output of running CMake with --debug-find option.

@Tsyvarev sorry, the long version of my answer was "since this question is specific to using curl with CMake using find_package, and since I can't use the target CMake and the target config files to do so, that means I have to link curl using other CMake commands, that would change the scope of the question.

"since I can't use the target CMake and the target config files to do so" - This is again wrong implication. I never told that you cannot use CMake modules for search the curl. I could be that your toolchain or environment setup are not quite correct. But again, for make a conclusion we need more debugging details.

@Tsyvarev I added the output of --debug-find. What I don't understand is what I can do about it if what you said was true: the only part of the toolchain that search for curl is CMake, that cannot use the target config files, but the host ones are of a wrong version and search in the wrong places. Using the target cmake is not feasible

find_package could work in MODULE mode or in CONFIG mode. While these search modes have different internal mechanisms, both are able to locate a package anywhere, including the root path during cross-compiling. So you shouldn't be confused with the fact that find_package(CURL) uses FindCURL.cmake module shipped with CMake - that CMake module is not limited to search only on the host machine.

In your output I see no paths like lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf or include/arm-linux-gnueabihf, so CMake doesn't search there. You probably need to specify set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE arm-linux-gnueabihf) in your toolchain file.

Thanks, it worked! Three questions though: 1) you said "So you shouldn't feed modules, written for that CMake, to CMake on your host machine", I guess here we were forced to do that? 2) did I need to specify CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE because otherwise CMake wouldn't have know the fs structure of the sysroot, right? 3) CURL on the target needed some libraries that CMake couldn't find on its own, I needed to manually add a bunch of target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} -l:libnghttp2.so.14). Is because the host module was linking against different versions, and there are no symlinks, right?
